# Inverse Laplace Transform

Tags: integral-transforms, inverse-laplace

What's the inverse laplace transform of $$\frac{s}{(s-1/2)^2+1}\:?$$

Comment: Wolfram alpha to the rescue! (:

http://www.wolframalpha.com/input/?i=What%27s%20the%20inverse%20laplace%20transform%20of%20s/%28%28s-.5%29%5E2%2b1%29?%20

Answer (score 1):

**Hint:**
$$\mathcal{L}(e^{-at}\cos\omega t) = \frac{s + a}{(s+a)^2 + \omega^2}$$
$$\mathcal{L}(e^{-at}\sin\omega t) = \frac{\omega}{(s+a)^2 + \omega^2}.$$

So maybe you can rewrite $$\frac{s}{(s-0.5)^2 + 1}$$ as a sum of two such functions and then take the inverse Laplace transform.

**Alternatively:** If you don't mind dealing with complex numbers, you might consider decomposing your function via partial fractions and using $\mathcal{L}(e^{at}) = 1/(s-a)$, though this might be annoying as a calculation (I haven't worked out the details).

Comment: Blah, seems so obvious now. Must be because it's 4 am. Thanks a bunch =)

Comment: @Anthony: Yeah, late night calculations are like that.  No problem at all.  :-)